# Spring-React frontend-maven-plugin not working

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm following the documentation is https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/ to build a React app that uses Spring. The spring part was fine until it gets to the part where recommends to install the node and npm modules with a plugin. I have the problem that this plugin does not do what it supposed to do. I've checked the documentation and it establish some executions (I don't really know how the plugins work). I introduce those executions, but I still can't see the React app render in the brower at localhost:8080.

This is the plugin that they use in the spring documentation. Just like that. I hope anybody who has followed this tutorial could help me.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can run React Frontend and SpringBoot Backend on the same port and Package them as a single artifact !!

> Here is the [Github](https://github.com/arpan-banerjee7/demo-spring-react-maven-plugin) link of the demo project that I am going to
> explain here

Spring Boot can serve static content from `src/main/resources/static` folder. We will exploit the above mentioned feature of Spring Boot to serve the single page of the react project. We will serve a html page from the static folder in the target directory, not in the source directory.

The **Project structure**-

[image]

First, create a spring boot project with https://start.spring.io. Add the Web dependency. Set the groupId and artifactId to whatever you want. Generate the project and unzip it into your project directory.

Or, if you are using Spring Tools Suite you can simply click
`File->New->Spring Starter Project` and mention the required details to create a spring boot project.

The `frontend` folder inside `src/main` should have your react application build using  [create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html).

**So, there are two steps-**

1. create a production build of the frontend.
2. copy the production build into ${target/classes/}.

**We we will use two maven plugins and [Thymleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/) for that.**

1. [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) for step 1.
2. [maven-resources-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) for step 2.

**For [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) at Step 1--** If you closely look at the `pom.xml` there I have mentioned the `src` directroy from where [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) will take the files, create the production build and place the contents inside the output directory mentioned(inside `src/main/frontend/build`).

```
 <workingDirectory>${frontend-src-dir}</workingDirectory>
 <installDirectory>${project.build.directory}</installDirectory>
```

**For [maven-resources-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) at step 2--** It will take the production build that was just created by [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) and place it inside your root directory then `target/classes/static`.

**Then we will use [Thymleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/)** to serve the static content from the `target/classes/static` using a rest endpoint in the controller. Or else you have to type in the name of the `html file`, like `http://localhost:8080/index.html`

Your **pom.xml** should look like this-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.springreact</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Run React Frontend and SpringBoot Backend on the same port.</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <frontend-src-dir>${project.basedir}/src/main/frontend</frontend-src-dir>
        <node.version>v14.15.4</node.version>
        <yarn.version>v1.16.0</yarn.version>
        <frontend-maven-plugin.version>1.7.6</frontend-maven-plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>

                <configuration>
                    <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
                    <yarnVersion>${yarn.version}</yarnVersion>
                    <workingDirectory>${frontend-src-dir}</workingDirectory>
                    <installDirectory>${project.build.directory}</installDirectory>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install-frontend-tools</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-yarn</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>yarn-install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>yarn</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>build-frontend</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>yarn</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>position-react-build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/static</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${frontend-src-dir}/build</directory>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is the **Controller** code.

```
package com.springreact.demo.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @GetMapping("")
    public ModelAndView home() {
        ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView("index");
        return mav;
    }

}
```

If you follow the above mentioned steps , you should see your React App being spun up on `http://localhost:8080/`.

[image]

*If you still have some doubts then you can checkout the comprehensive blog that I have written on it. Here are the links  of the blog on two different platforms, you can choose whichever you are comfortable with.*

Dev Community- https://dev.to/arpan_banerjee7/run-react-frontend-and-springboot-backend-on-the-same-port-and-package-them-as-a-single-artifact-14pa

Medium- https://arpan-banerjee7.medium.com/run-react-frontend-and-springboot-backend-on-the-same-port-and-package-them-as-a-single-artifact-a790c9e10ac1

Answer (score 1):

I followed **the same tutorial** and stuck at the same point: the frontend-maven-plugin seems not working. In addition, the codebase that author provided looks not well organized to me, e.g. two `pom.xml` files, one in project root folder, the other in basic folder.

Here is what I figured out, and finally worked:

1. In `pom.xml` add the `frontend-maven-plugin` in `plugins` along with the scripts you want it to execute. Make sure you include the version tag and supply the latest version (you can find the version information in [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin)), otherwise the plugin won't be resolved.

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- For the sake of simplicity, -->
        <!-- other plugins are omitted. -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <nodeVersion>v14.17.3</nodeVersion>
                        <npmVersion>7.18.1</npmVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>npm install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>install</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>webpack build</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>webpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

2. Create `package.json` file in the project root folder, i.e. same location as `pom.xml` and paste following content:

```json
{
  "name": "spring-data-rest-and-reactjs",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Demo of ReactJS + Spring Data REST",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@github.com:spring-guides/tut-react-and-spring-data-rest.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "rest",
    "hateoas",
    "spring",
    "data",
    "react"
  ],
  "author": "Greg L. Turnquist",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-react-and-spring-data-rest/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-react-and-spring-data-rest",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "rest": "^1.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack --watch -d --output ./target/classes/static/built/bundle.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "webpack": "^4.19.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

3. Create `webpack.config.js` file in project root folder, i.e. the same location as `pom.xml` and paste following content:

```js
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main/js/app.js',
    devtool: 'sourcemaps',
    cache: true,
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './src/main/resources/static/built/bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: path.join(__dirname, '.'),
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
                    }
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

4. Copy `client.js` and the whole `api` folder in the same directory to your project. The `app.js` uses `client.js` which uses the two `.js` files in the `api` folder. You can find the source code of the three files in [the tutorial repository](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-react-and-spring-data-rest/tree/master/basic/src/main/js).
5. Now you should have everything in order to make React work in this project. While depending on what IDE you're using, it may still "NOT WORK". Let me explain more about what I mean:

   1. if you are using command line to run the project, then simply type `./mvnw spring-boot:run` in the project root folder and it should work like a charm.
   2. if you are using the little green triangle to run application in IntelliJ like me, you have to edit run/debug configuration in order to make it work; otherwise the application can run successfully but there is no `bundle.js` generated whatsoever:

   First, open IntelliJ -> Run -> Edit Configurations
   [image: Open Edit Run/Debug Configuration]

   Secondly, click on the `+` button in `Before Launch` section and select `Run Maven Goal`
   [image: Add Run Maven Goal]

   Thirdly, type `generate-resources` in command line and click OK. We choose this command as mentioned in `frontend-maven-plugin` git repo, if not sepecified, the goal is executed in `generate-resources` phase.
   [image: Add generate-resources command]

   Finally, you can create a maven goal to clean everything before build. Here is what `Before launch` looks like:
   [image: Final before launch]

   Now click on the green triangle to run application and you will get the same result as mentioned in the tutorial (except there is no boarders in the employee list since we don't have the `.css` file).

Some final thoughts:

1. You add `frontend-maven-plugin` to use `node` and `npm` in your project.
2. You add `package.json` to install necessary JavaScript modules, e.g. React.js.
3. You add `webpack.config.js` to instruct webpack to transpile the javascript files into a single file named `bundle.js` and output it to the static folder of the project
4. You add many `execution` and `goal` tags in `pom.xml` to automate step 2 and 3.
5. You execute the maven goals to start the automation process.

Answer (score 0):

If your project structure looks like the following:

```
frontend/ -> React application
src/ -> Spring Boot application
```

You can bundle the React application with the `frontend-maven-plugin` with the following configuration:

```
<build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/frontend/build</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <targetPath>public/</targetPath>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>install node and npm</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>npm install</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
              <arguments>install</arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>npm build</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
              <environmentVariables>
                <CI>true</CI>
              </environmentVariables>
              <arguments>run build</arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <workingDirectory>frontend</workingDirectory>
          <nodeVersion>v12.18.0</nodeVersion>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

If your project structure differs, you have to adjust the `workingDirectory` and the first resources configuration and point it to your folder.

This plugin basically executes several `npm` commands to test and build your React application and with the `resources` configuration, you extend the standard directory to include inside your `.jar`. Your frontend application is then accessible at `http://localhost:8080`.

You can find a running example for this [here](https://rieckpil.de/howto-up-and-download-files-with-react-and-spring-boot/).